# Plotting multiple columns on x-axis as series in R

Tags: r, ggplot2

I have the following dataframe:

```
  STATE STATEFP `2000` `2005` `2010` `2015`
  <chr>   <dbl>  <dbl>  <dbl>  <dbl>  <dbl>
1 AL          1  0.958  0.953  0.953  0.944
2 AR          5  0.373  0.354  0.322  0.314
3 AZ          4  0.493  0.514  0.583  0.541
4 CA          6  0.604  0.675  0.608  0.326
5 CO          8  0.819  0.818  0.862  0.856
6 CT          9  0.870  0.817  0.748  0.791
```

Now I want to make a line plot where 2000, 2005, 2010 and 2015 are place on the x-axis and the values in those columns are plotted. Each line should then have a color which corresponds with the right State.

Do I have to transfer my data or is it easier?

Comment: A small request, for future questions: the output you've provided is mostly good, but `tibble`'s output here requires some cleanup for us to use (the `\`` surrounding atypical column names, and the class row with `<chr>`, etc). While this is better than many questions, it is often easier when the question includes the output from `dput` (as in my answer), so that we have an unambiguous copy of the data. Minor, really, but any little bit can help sometimes. Thanks!

Answer (score 2):

Hi you can use tidyr's pivot longer for this:

```
library(tidyr)
library(ggplot2)
iris %>% pivot_longer(Sepal.Length:Petal.Width) %>% 
  ggplot(aes(name,value, colour= Species))+geom_boxplot()
```

- pivot_longer rearranges the first four columns to longer format
  creating the name (=former column name) column and a value column.
- ggplot plots the piped output using geom_boxplot

Answer (score 2):

`ggplot2` expects "long" data, not wide.

```r
library(ggplot2)
# library(tidyr) # pivot_longer
tidyr::pivot_longer(dat, `2000`:`2015`, names_to = "year") %>%
  ggplot(., aes(year, value)) +
  geom_path(aes(color = STATE, group = STATE))
```

[image]

---

Data

```r
dat <- structure(list(STATE = c("AL", "AR", "AZ", "CA", "CO", "CT"), STATEFP = c(1L, 5L, 4L, 6L, 8L, 9L), `2000` = c(0.958, 0.373, 0.493, 0.604, 0.819, 0.87), `2005` = c(0.953, 0.354, 0.514, 0.675, 0.818, 0.817), `2010` = c(0.953, 0.322, 0.583, 0.608, 0.862, 0.748), `2015` = c(0.944, 0.314, 0.541, 0.326, 0.856, 0.791)), class = "data.frame", row.names = c("1", "2", "3", "4", "5", "6"))
```

Comment: Thanks! I already had the longer frame but I pivoted that one wider. Your tip about ''geplot expects long data'' did the job. Thanks a million!